# Find the longest palindromic substring

Tags: python, algorithm

Given a string S, find the longest palindromic substring.
For example:

Input: "aaaabaaa"
Output: "aaabaaa"

Comment: Have you done anything? We aren't here to write your code.

Comment: You can refer the link https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-palindrome-substring-set-1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way I could imagine is:

```
def longestPalindrome(A):
    rev = A[::-1]
    l = len(A)
    while l > 0:
        for i in xrange(0, len(A) - l + 1):
            half = int(l / 2)
            left = A[i : i + half]
            right = rev[len(A) - (i + l) : len(A) - (i + l - half)]
            if left == right:
                return A[i:i+l]
        l -= 1
    return None
```